# JMeter Variable Behavior Issue

Tags: jmeter

I am facing some odd behavior with when I am trying to run a JMeter Script with 1 Thread and 3 iteration.

Scenario:
I am saving the data which is coming via the response to a variable, use that variable and process that data in Beanshell PostProcessor and using in some other request. The variable is working fine when I run with 1 Thread 1 Iteration but when I am running the same with 1 Thread and 3 iteration, the variable value is not as expected.

Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

String data = vars.get("itemList");
String[] dataArray = data.split(",");
ArrayList fullList = new ArrayList();
if(dataArray.length==1){
    String s = dataArray[0].substring(2,dataArray[0].length()-2);
    fullList.add(s);
}
else{
    for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
        String s = dataArray[i];
        if(i==0){
            s = s.substring(2,s.length()-1);
        }
        else if(i==dataArray.length-1){
            s = s.substring(1,s.length()-2);
        }
        else{
            s = s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
        }
        fullList.add(s);
    }
}

String result = "";
String fullResult = "";
// Extractor

// request string
String request = "";
for (Object x : fullList) {

            // For Long form of string
            if (fullResult.equals(""))
                fullResult = x.toString();
            else
                fullResult = fullResult + ":" + x.toString();

            // For short form of string
            String st = x.toString();
            st = st.substring(2, 8);
            if (result.equals("")){
                result = st;
                request = "{\"@number\":\""+st+"\"}";
            }
            else{
                result = result + ":" + st;
                request = request + ",{\"@number\":\""+st+"\"}";
            }
                
            // extracted.add(st);

        }
// vars.put("fullResult",)
log.info("FullResult >>>>> "+fullResult);
log.info("Result >>>>> "+result);
log.info("Request >>>>> "+request);
vars.put("vehicleList",request);
vars.put("vehicleFullNumberList",fullResult);
```

Comment: pls add more info, what is reponse? what do you expect for iteration 1, 2, and 3? What is odd behavior here?

Answer (score 0):

In its current state your question cannot be comprehensively answered as we need to know:

1. The value of `itemList` JMeter Variable for 1st and 2nd iteration
2. What is the "expected result"
3. What is the "actual result"

So far I can suggest the following hints:

1. Use [Debug Sampler/Post-Processor and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) to examine what JMeter Variables are defined and what are their values on each step.
2. Make sure that your Beanshell PostProcessor is properly located as it might be executed way more often that you expect, see [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) for more details.
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth migrating in any case